# Access host docker-machine from within container

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-machine

I have an image that I'm using to run my CI/CD builds (using GitLab CE). I'd like to deploy my app doing something like this from within the container:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env manager)"
sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml web
```

However, I'd like the docker-machine to access machines defined on the host system since the container will be destroyed and I don't want to include access details in the image.

I've tried a few things

**Accessing the Remote Host via `docker-machine`**

- Create the docker-machine on the host and mount the `MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH` so that it is available to the container
- Connect to the remote docker-machine manually from within the container and setting the `MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH` equal to a mounted volume
- Mounting the docker socket

In both cases, I can see the machine storage is persisted, but whenever I create a new container and run `docker-machine ls` none of the machines are listed.

**Accessing the Remote Host via `DOCKER_HOST`**

- Forward the remote machine docker port to the host docker port `docker-machine ssh manager-1 -N -L 2376:localhost:2376`
- `export DOCKER_HOST=:2376`
- Tell docker to use the same certs that are used by docker-machine: `export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1` and `export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/manager-‌​1`
- Test with `docker info`

This gives me `error during connect: Get https://localhost:2376/v1.26/info: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Any ideas on how I can perform a remote deployment from within a container?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a diagram to try and help better communicate the scenario.

[image: architectur]

Comment: i would not mount `docker.sock` like has been advised.  see this article for information https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/ you are opening up a large security hole.

Comment: would you consider this much of a risk if the only container running on the socket is a build container?

Comment: normally you would not want to run a container within a container.  if you need access to volumes you should `--link` instead or with the `docker >= 1.12` create a network overlay.  there is nothing wrong with using a container to start other containers, just have them started on the host machine and not inside of the container.  doing containers in containers is an anti-pattern that you will find hard to manage over time.

Comment: what you are trying to do can be done easier by combining gitlab with ansible.  e.g. build container with gitlab ce -> passes, next build step is execute ansible playbook to deploy/update docker container on host vm.  this is the easiest way to do what you want without introducing security risks.

Comment: yeah I'm not starting a container within a container. I was simply mounting the docker socket so that I can `build` + `push` and trying to `stack deploy` on a remote machine (not within the build container). But I think you're right on the last comment, that seems to make the most sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Don't use docker-machine for this.

Docker-machine stores files in $HOME/.docker/machine, so when you restart with a fresh copy of this folder, all previously defined machines will be removed. You could store this folder as a volume, but there's a much easier way for your purposes.

The solution is to mount the docker socket, and either as root or from a user with the same gid as the docker socket (note that group names themselves inside and outside the container may not match, so gid is important), run your `docker ...` commands as normal. You can skip the `docker-machine` eval completely since you are running the commands against the local docker socket.

If you need to run commands remotely, I find it easier to define the `DOCKER_HOST` and `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` variables manually rather than using `docker-machine`.

Comment: So, I already mount the socket for doing things like building images. If I setup a tunnel from the host to the remote machine: `docker-machine ssh manager-1 -N -L 2376:localhost:2376` and then try to set `DOCKER_HOST=:2376`, and run `docker info` I get: Get http://localhost:2376/v1.26/info: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02".

Comment: I then tried `export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1` and `export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/manager-1` and now `docker info` gives `error during connect: Get https://localhost:2376/v1.26/info: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: Looks like you are still trying to use docker-machine. It's also not clear what commands and file/directories you are using from the host vs inside the container. These are by definition not the same. See this link for more details on using remote docker sockets: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Comment: Sorry, the comments above are being run on the host machine just to make sure I can connect to the remote machine using this method (so far that's a no). Note that the remote machine was created by the host machine using `docker-machine create ...` hence why I am pointing to the docker machine cert paths and using `docker-machine ssh` to forward the port.

Comment: I've added a diagram in my original post

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to communicate from your CI container to the Docker host you can simply mount the Docker socket when starting the CI container:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <gitlab-image>
```

Now you can run docker commands on the host from within the CI container.

Comment: Yeah - so I'm already doing that. I can do things like `docker build` and `docker login` but when I want to actually deploy to a remote machine, `docker-machine ls` shows no machines. However, running `docker-machine ls` on the host shows several machines. Is there a socket that needs to be mounted for docker machine?

Comment: this should not be advised.  mounting the `docker.sock` is a security issue.  https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/ there are a lot of articles about this, if you are using docker in production this is not advised.